# Get the div id / class when windows.location is fired

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a clickable div (windows.location) and I am trying to display a modal popup when this div is clicked.

here is my div box:

```
<div class="category_box" onclick="window.location='/Products/@cityName/@categoryName'">
            <div class="category_box_catName">
                @link
            </div>
            <div class="category_box_NumOfProds">                   
                @Resources.Categories_GetByCity_NumProdsText
            </div>
        </div>
```

I was trying to get the class of this div when it clicked but could not make it work:

```
if ($(event.target).hasClass('div[class*=category_box]')) {
    $('#mdlPopup').show();
}
```

Then I was trying to change the onclick and to add inside it $('#mdlPopup').show();

```
<div class="category_box"  onclick="$('#mdlPopup').show(); window.location='/Products/@cityName/@categoryName'">
...
```

but this is also not working for me.

Comment: Changing location kills any script and what is md1Popup?

Comment: You must use window.open() instead of window.location to get popup. Anyway, I strongly recommend you not to do it, because popups probality that browser will block you.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the windows.location from the div and use this code to make the div clickable. then I can get the class from the div using:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

            $('[class^=category_box]').click(function () {
                $('#mdlPopup').show();
                window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
                return false;
            });
        });
```